# select checkbox by name and check if it checked javascript

Tags: javascript, select, checkbox, input

I am trying to test if checkbox is checked. 
I have more inputs and they have different names. 
I managed to select the input but I can't seem to check if it wa selected. If I add to the condition '= true' it is checked once I load the page. If I leave it just .checked it doesn't do anything

1. Have I selected the input right? Please note I want to select it by name rather than id or class
2. Why is it that once the page loads my condition for if statement doesn't work?

---

```
<input type="checkbox" name="name1">
<input type="checkbox" name="name2">
<input type="checkbox" name="name3">
<input type="checkbox" name="name4">


const firstInput = document.getElementsByName('name1');
if (firstInput[0].checked) {
    console.log('checked');
}
```

Comment: You are looking for an element with name "1" but you got element with a name "name1".

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I meant 'name1'. Once I checked it the console should print checked but it doesn't

Comment: Your code works. Where do you perform that check - in a function, in a listener?

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting element with name "1" but don`t have element with such name.
If you want to select all inputs which name attribute starts with "name":

```
const firstInput = document.querySelectorAll('[name^=name]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add attribute to that input. Attach an onclick listener and invoke

> getAttribute
>   setAttribute

to manipulate 'checked' attribute;

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()" name="name1">
<input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()" name="name2">
<input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()" name="name3">
<input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()" name="name4">


function myFunction() {
  var $element = document.getElementsByName('name1')[0];
  var checked = $element.getAttribute('checked') === 'true';
  $element.setAttribute('checked', !checked);
  console.log($element.getAttribute('checked'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I managed to do it adding the event listener to the checkbox.